# Отправлять данные на сервер с Androida

Tags: java, android, http, gps

Хотелось бы грамотно отправлять данные на сервер с `Androida`. Мой вариант хорош?

Мне нужно отправлять 1 раз в 2 минуты данные (координаты) на сервер, подходит ли этот код отправки данных для моих целей? Очень хотелось бы реализовать это грамотно.
Вот рабочий код отвечающий за отправку координат на сервер методом `POST`, он запускается в `IntentService`, который включается раз в 2 минуты.

```
public class LocationService extends IntentService {

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // тут получаем GPS координаты
      ...
    // тут устанавливаем соединение и отправляем координаты
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             // указываем адрес вашего сервера и путь принимающего скрипта
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysait.ru/test.php");
             try {
             List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(2);
             // отправляемое сообщение
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", "GPS координаты"));
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
             httpclient.execute(httppost); // отправка на сервер
             Log.i(TAG, "Данные отправлены на сервер");
             } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // ...
             } catch (IOException e) {
             // ...
            }
    }
    }
```

1. Если в этом варианте есть серьезные, критические проблемы укажите их, пожалуйста.
2. Ваши любые рекомендации по данному коду и в целом по реализации моей задачи.
3. У `Androida` два `HTTP` клиента: `HttpURLConnection` и `Apache HttpClient`, какой больше подходит для моей задачи и почему?

Ну и вопрос на засыпку, не такой важный:)

- Данный код не обрабатывает ответ от сервера о том что координаты были доставлены на сервер, но ответ от сервера все равно будет приходить? Этот ответ можно как то отключить, чтоб сервер только принимал координаты и ничего не отвечал при этом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечаю по порядку!

1. критических ошибок в общем то нету, но нужно помнить, что некоторые сервера принимают header на вход.
2. см. выше
3. Google рекомендует использовать HttpURLConnection, так как на его создание нужно намного меньше ресурсов. Но можно и обойтись HttpClient, но инстанс на него лучше держать в сингелтоне.
4. Не хочешь получать ответ, ну и не нужно тогда вызывать getResponse. Можешь так и оставить! :)

Answer (score 1):

используйте http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Все очень просто и быстро!